# Magento2: Add new top-menu item in customer menu

Tags: magento2

How to add a new item in the dropdown of the customer menu on the frontend?
[image]

I want to add a new item below my account.

Comment: Can you please share, what kind of Link you want to add in that section?

Comment: @Sumit your solution is working for me. Thanks. How i change position ?

Comment: Good to hear, you can change it with the before and after attributes given in **default.xml** file

Comment: Thanks. The only issue is that it is not coming in mobile.

Comment: Are you using a different theme for the mobile?

Comment: no. i am using same theme

Comment: OK, so we need to debug it for mobile view. Because for me it is working on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it by following the below steps

Create `default.xml` file in your custom module with below content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Link" name="custom-link" after="my-account-link"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create `Link.php` with the below content

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

/**
 * Customer account dropdown link
 */
class Link extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'Vendor_Module::link.phtml';

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHref()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('custom-link');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getLabel()
    {
        return __('Custom Link');
    }
}
```

Create `link.phtml` with below content

```
<?php
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/* @var $block \Vendor\Module\Block\Link */
?>
<li class="link custom wishlist" data-bind="scope: 'credit'">
    <a <?= $block->getLinkAttributes() ?>><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getLabel()) ?>
        <span>Custom Link</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

**Hope it helps!!!**